# F# TupleGet ActivePattern usage

Tags: f#, tuples

I would like to know how to extract values out of a tuple Expression in F# when using quotations. If for example, I have a quotation `<@ fst(sample_tuple) @>`, how do I deconstruct the tuple quotation to get out the values?

Answer (score 2):

The unquote library [1] contains an eval function that is reported as being faster than the FSharp.PowerPack.

[1] http://code.google.com/p/unquote

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the output of sending a quotation like that to FSI, your quotation doesn't use `TupleGet`, it uses a `Call` to the generic `Fst` method, so you can't destructure it using `TupleGet`.

A quotation like `<@ match sample_tuple with | a, _ -> a @>` would use `TupleGet` to extract the first element.

Comment: Hi kvb, thanks a lot for your response. I'm actually not particular about using TupleGet. I just need to get out the values when deconstructing the quotation. Could you help with sample code in this regard?

Comment: @Tolu - what do you mean by "get out the values"?  If you want to evaluate the quotation (getting the result of `fst sample_tuple` in this case), you could try using the F# PowerPack.  FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll contains an `Eval` extension method on quotations.